# ListGrid with Smartgwt4 not populating data when accessed via F5 Firepass

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid, f5

ListGrid with Smartgwt4 not populating data when accessed via F5 Firepass (Firewall) , doing an extranet access in mobile device.

Not able to see the data in the grid.   I can see it is accessing the server and getting the data upto the data source.

When i access in my local machine it display the grid as expected.

Any help on this, much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: After a thorough research , found the culprit.   Listgrid.setShowRowNumber(true)  -- this was causing the problem for me.   The following settings worked for me. listGrid.setAutoFetchData(false);
  listGrid.setShowEmptyMessage(false);
  listGrid.setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.MULTIPLE);  
     listGrid.setAlternateRecordStyles(true);

Answer (score 0):

After a thorough research , found the culprit.

```
 listgrid.setShowRowNumber(true)
```

this was causing the problem for me when i try to display the grid data in wifi-device accessed through a firewall

The following settings worked for me for sure. other attributes to be tested and verified.

```
 listGrid.setAutoFetchData(false); 
 listGrid.setShowEmptyMessage(false); 
 listGrid.setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.MULTIPLE); 
 listGrid.setAlternateRecordStyles(true);
```